# Print histograms next to each other in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am working with R and the package "ggplot2". I am trying to print several histograms next to each other:

`library(ggplot2)
h=ggplot(data, aes(x=Return1))
h+ geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1)
h + facet_grid(Return1 + Return2)`

It sends an error "No layers in plot".

Here an example of data:

`data=matrix(rnorm(50, 0, 1), ncol=5)
colnames(data)=c("Return1", "Return2", "Return3", "Return4", "Return5")
rownames(data)=c("1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004")`

The purpose is to have an histogram with the values of my first variable "Return1", another histogram with my the values of my second variable "Return2", ...

I'm not sure that I'm using the right function (facet_grid) to do that.
Thank you for your help on this.

swiMa

Comment: provide an example data

Comment: Here an example of data.
Thank for you help though.
`data=matrix(rnorm(50, 0, 1), ncol=5)
colnames(data)=c("Return1", "Return2", "Return3", "Return4", "Return5")
rownames(data)=c("1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004")`

Comment: i posted a complete answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data <- structure(c(-0.447315711911355, 0.670646511357067, 0.28805337765816, 
0.210323243582978, 0.558951367403988, 0.607248748494035, -1.16412611819213, 
0.0915424491269807, 0.469191549286902, -0.619038988584179, -0.659390830669932, 
-0.924810741449363, -1.42269762267215, -0.13593956988495, -1.92882493234572, 
-1.27638233136087, 1.3816213467106, 0.365757310517179, -0.479538532782686, 
0.70769126786196, -0.326429694012458, -1.01751602957572, 0.555459246627799, 
-0.355015029145993, -0.065915904785214, 0.576685372310354, 1.08050319208107, 
-0.697995949639672, 0.661562203593662, 0.0968130184654234, -0.672212026424006, 
0.0269233940788362, 0.661236459007207, -0.507557327616088, -0.800274398837844, 
1.93302333485735, -1.28135392022731, 1.33095400120017, -0.377753506417346, 
0.700663669871313, -1.08566228220391, -1.08906574084574, -1.04577335310861, 
0.956870855865283, -2.21389083133313, 0.299118475920725, 0.523434618906021, 
0.0428254530914905, 0.443157396704438, 2.00841231202171), .Dim = c(10L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Return1", "Return2", "Return3", 
"Return4", "Return5")))
```

## You can use a simple hist function to bring all together

```
par(mfrow=c(1,5))
hist(data[,1])
hist(data[,2])
hist(data[,3])
hist(data[,4])
hist(data[,5])
```

## you can use the gplot

you need to install a package as follows

```
install.packages("gridExtra")
```

Note:
don't forget to load the library and 
add any needed package or library it requires

```
p1<- qplot(data[,1], binwidth=.5)
p2<- qplot(data[,2], binwidth=.5)
p3<- qplot(data[,3], binwidth=.5)
p4<- qplot(data[,4], binwidth=.5)
p5<- qplot(data[,5], binwidth=.5)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4,p5, ncol=2)
```

## or you can use the ggplot as follows:

```
row.names (data) <- NULL
df<- as.data.frame(data)
p1<- ggplot(df, aes(df[,1])) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
p2<- ggplot(df, aes(df[,2])) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
p3<- ggplot(df, aes(df[,3])) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
p4<- ggplot(df, aes(df[,4])) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
p5<- ggplot(df, aes(df[,5])) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4,p5, ncol=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use facet_grid, you need to create a column (named returns for example) in data that contains : Return1, Return2, ...
And then : `h + facet_grid(.~returns)`
But I think that the variable you use in facet_grid must be different from x in aes()

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is what I've seen from examples online. With the iris data, it used "species", and do the charts according to that variable, but in my example I just one to print charts next to each other like with `par(mfrow=c(1,2)) #two histograms on one line`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is awkward, but here is a start on the answer.  Edit your question to incorporate reproducible data, extend this answer, and see what else you need.

```
data <- matrix(rnorm(50, 0, 1), ncol=5) 
colnames(data) <- c("Return1", "Return2", "Return3", "Return4", "Return5")
rownames(data) <- c("1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004") <- 

df <-  as.data.frame(data) # since ggplot2 requires a data frame
df.m <- 

ggplot(df, aes(x=Return1, y=Return2)) + #added the second variable as y
  geom_histogram(stat = "identity") + # need to set the stat
  facet_grid(Return1 ~ Return2) # note the tilde operator
```

Comment: I get some errors with your code. `Stacking not well defined when ymin !=0`
Nemo could find below a solution for what I was looking for.
Thank you for your help also!